# How to interpret two formulas for time averaged mean square displacement and autocorrelation function?

Tags: soft-question, intuition, correlation, means

This is a two part question:

---

**Part 1:**

In [a (totally fascinating) paper](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v12/n2/abs/nphys3553.html) studying the distance between two domains of a protein in an MD simulation, the time-averaged mean square displacement of the distance between the two domains, $R(t)$, is given by:

$$ \overline{\delta^{2}(\Delta;t)} = \frac{1}{t-\Delta} \int_{0}^{t-\Delta} [R(t'+ \Delta)-R(t')]^{2} \ dt'$$

where $\Delta$ is the "lag time" and $t$ is the total observation time of the simulation.

I'm familiar with the normal average value of a function $f(x)$ between $a$ and $b$:

$$ \overline{f(x)}_{(a,b)} = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx, $$

and I understand that $[R(t'+\Delta)-R(t')]^2$ is the (squared) measure of the difference in the distance between the two domains after a certain "lag time" $\Delta$, and that $\overline{\delta^{2}(\Delta;t)}$ is measuring the average of the this measure over a time $(t-\Delta)$.

What I don't understand is this: what information does this convey? What's the purpose of changing the time over which the square displacement is averaged?

For example, in a simulation with total observation time $t=100$ ps, $\overline{\delta^{2}(\Delta;t)} \propto \Delta^{1.5}$, with $\Delta \in (10^{-1}\text{ps},10^1\text{ps})$.

At the lower end, the integral is averaging the distance between the domains after a lag time of $10^{-1}$ps over ~$100$ ps. At the upper end, the integral is averaging the distance between the domains after a lag time of $10$ps, over $90$ps. What information does the relationship between $\Delta$ and $\overline{\delta^2(\Delta;t)}$ convey? The fact that the time-averaged mean square displacement goes up as the lag time goes up means... what exactly?

---

**Part 2:**

The same paper defines the normalized auto-correlation function of the distance between the domains as: $ C(\Delta;t) = C'(\Delta;t)/C'(0;t)$, where:

$$ C'(\Delta;t)=\frac{1}{t-\Delta}\int_{0}^{t-\Delta}\delta R(t')\delta R(t' + \Delta) \ dt' $$

where $\delta R(t)=R(t)-\langle R \rangle$; in other words, how far the distance between the domains is from the average inter-domain distance.

Here, I have to admit more ignorance than in Part 1. I understand that the auto-correlation function is supposed to be some measure of the similarity of a function to himself at different times, but I don't understand how this function achieves that measure. I wish I had a more pointed question to ask, but I'm hoping that someone can help anyway. I understand if it's too broad.

Answer (score 1):

If the time averaged msd is increasing in lagtime, this means, that the integral without the factor is growing faster than linear in lagtime. Thus,R(t) and R(t+lag) grow farther apart ratber fast on average, if the lagtime grows.
For 2: i'm not completly able to explain it to you, but you could start with simple functions for R and see what happens. 
Also it looks a lot like the convolution of R with itself. On option would be establishing the relation to the convolution and getting an intuition about that broader concept.

Comment: What do you mean by the integral without the factor? Just $\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t} R(t')^2 \ dt'$?

Comment: No, without the fraction in front.

Comment: How would adding a fraction out front affect the rate of growth? It's just a constant

Comment: The fraction is a function of delta, we are talking about growth in delta.

Comment: Ahhhh yes thank you